# CodeIgniter routing link in routes.php

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-hmvc

I am confused when I try to route from `localhost/admin` to `localhost/index.php/admin`

`localhost/index.php/admin` - this link working fine.

I have tried:

```
$route['admin'] = 'index.php/admin';
$route['default_controller'] = 'front';
```

`localhost/index.php/front` is working fine when I open `localhost` it displays front page which is not working.

I am using CodeIgniter HMVC in this example.

I added extra code as it was not allowing me to post the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you need to remove `index.php` in your URL

Go to **config/config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/projectname/';
$config['index_page'] = ''; # remove index.php on here
```

In **.htaccess** - place outside application folder.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

And in **routes.php**

remove this `$route['admin'] = 'index.php/admin';`

Comment: it gives internal server error on adding .htaaccess